# How to nudge over the bar numerical labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I adjust the position in geom_text to distribute the column labels over each of their respective columns, currently they are all aligned on top of each other (see picture)[image]

```
ggplot(ESCd, aes(factor(S),fill = ESC9)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="count", position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1, position = "identity")
```

Comment: Try changing `geom_text`  `position = "identity"` to `position = "dodge"`

Comment: please include a picture of the desired layout ... handwritten on existing picture would be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

We could use `position = position_dodge()`:

Here is an example with the built in `diamonds` dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(factor(cut),fill = factor(color))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="count", position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
            vjust = -0.25, color = "black", size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: perfect thank you so much